# What does a checkmarked item mean in Somnium?

Tags: ai-the-somnium-files

When I replay a Somnium section sometimes some of the items will have a checkmark next to them. This can appear even if I haven't performed every possible action with that item.

What does a checkmark next to an item mean?

[image: Two checkmarked items]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items with a checkmark appear to have an action that will unlock a mental lock needed to progress the plot.

[image: Solving mental lock #1]